# MVC buttons linking to image

Tags: c#, button, controller, routes

I am new to C# so I am having trouble with an image link to a controller.

I created this link that routes a user to a controller. Right now its a submit button that is given the word "Sign up Now" but instead of doing this I want to use an image. I had not  trouble creating the link for just a simple button but cant figure out how to do this with an image.

This is my code

```
    @Html.SubmitButton("Sign Up Now!", OrdersController.AddSubscriptionRoute, new { pl=1, itemCode = Model.ItemCode, webId = Model.WebID, webCategoryId = Model.WebCategoryID, priceTypeId = Model.PriceTypeID }, null, ActionEmphasis.Callout)
```

I want to use image

```
 <img src="/_resources/images/content/callout.jpg" style="float:right">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have the form post to a particular action, you only need something like the following:

```
<form action="<%:Url.RouteUrl("Your Route Here");%>" method="post">
 <!-- Html Input elements -->
 <input type="image" src="/_resources/images/content/callout.jpg" style="float:right;" alt="Submit" />
</form>
```

If you need to have multiple buttons on your form, consider this article:

http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/11/26/Supporting-multiple-submit-buttons-on-an-ASPNET-MVC-view.aspx